# problem in receiving data of post

Tags: php, android, post

I am facing problem to get data from post array in php. I used `var_dump($_POST)` for debugging.
It shows 0{}. I am sending data from a android application.I am not sure what is my problem.
Is it related to content type? My content type is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=" text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

My android code is

```
client=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/php_server/index.php");
            List<NameValuePair>p=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            p.add(new BasicNameValuePair("android","data received"));
            HttpEntity entity;

            try
            {   
                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(p));
                HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("socket connection", e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, since you're not getting anything I would trouble shoot the application POSTING correctly.

Comment: We will need to see some actual code.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem with [Android], maybe your code, try updating a snippet of your code, will see how it works. @David Nguyen: glad to see a Vietnamese on here ^^

Comment: Did a quick search, did you do the manifest part of this tutorial? http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android

Comment: @David Nguyen yes I did.

Answer (score -1):

Try to look at [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)
or try to get it by

```
<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```

Comment: (-1) you should provide the OP your approach and solution to the problem rather than posting thing that is not particularly related to the question, at least you explain something...